# reqexp optinal match in string

Tags: regex

I have a issue, i'm playing around with reqexp and now i hit a little issue, can't find a way around so its time to ask.

i have this 2 lines i want to reqexp on.

```
netplan.io [0.36.3] (0.40.1~18.04.3 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
nplan (0.40.1~18.04.3 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [all])
```

my reqexp today look like this. with ignore case, global and multiline.

```
(.*) \[(.*)] \((.*) (.*) \[(.*)]
```

my resualt right now is

```
Match 1
Full match  0-71    `netplan.io [0.36.3] (0.40.1~18.04.3 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64]`
Group 1.    0-10    `netplan.io`
Group 2.    12-18   `0.36.3`
Group 3.    21-35   `0.40.1~18.04.3`
Group 4.    36-63   `Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates`
Group 5.    65-70   `amd64`
```

The problem is i only got 1 match becures the secound line dont contain ( [....]) match, and what i want its take this match if its existes else i want to ignore it.

i have try a lot, but i don't relly understand it i think, so hope i can get help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the optional part into a non-capturing group, and make that non-capturing group optional with `?`. Also, to increase the efficiency of your pattern, and to ensure that the groups only match as much as they need to and no more, you should repeat the *negation* of the character a group is followed by, rather than using `.*` (which will require backtracking):

```
(\S*) (?:\[([^\]]*)] )?\((\S*) (.*) \[(\S*)]
```

https://regex101.com/r/b3wxun/2

Comment: Its look more right then my own, but still not give me the number: 0.36.3 in match one, but now its return both match, :)

Comment: Use the negation of the character a group is followed by instead of `.*` (more accurate match *and* much less unnecessary backtracking)

Comment: very nice, thanks a lot, now its working as i want it to work, :) thanks for helping, i will read up on S* never seen that before.

Comment: `\S` is basically just the opposite of `\s` - it matches any non-whitespace character